# update cells after NumberFormat vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a subroutine which changes the format of cells by column

```
Sub format_columns()

Application.Union(Columns("i"), Columns("k"), Columns("m")).Select

Selection.NumberFormat = "0%"

End Sub
```

The formatting is changed but I have to click into or `f2 and enter` each cell to change it for the formula to work.

I have tried:

`Application.EnableEvents = True`

`ScreenUpdating = True`

How can I update the Cells to the new format automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the number format before pasting the text, or set the values again to convert them to numbers:

```
Sub format_columns()
    For Each col In Range("I:I,K:K,M:M").Columns
        col.NumberFormat = "0%"
        col.Value = r.Value
    Next
End Sub
```